# "\n" or '\n' or std::endl to std::cout?

Tags: c++, string, character

It was many years now since I stopped using `std::endl` to end lines when writing to `std::cout`, and started using `"\n"` instead.

But now I start seeing more snippets of code using `'\n'` instead, and I started wonder what might be best.

Besides the obvious that one is a string, and the other a character, is there any advantage to using this:

```
std::cout << variable << '\n';
```

Over this:

```
std::cout << variable << "\n";
```

---

Late addition:

When I asked this question I seemed to think that newline `'\n'` flushed the buffer. Now I know that it *depends*.

By default `std::cin` is tied to the old C `stdin` `FILE*` stream, and `std::cout` is tied to `stdout`. The flushing on newline comes from this tying. By default `stdout`, if connected to a terminal, is line-buffered. That means a new line will flush its buffers. So when printing a newline using `std::cout`, that will lead to `stdout` being flushed.

If `stdout` is not connected to a terminal (for example the output has been redirected or is piped), or if the tie between `std::cout` and `stdout` is broken, then newlines will not flush anything.

Comment: interesting question, I'd also like to see an answer to that question. :) Also, why did you stop using `std::endl`?

Comment: @Constantinius http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n

Comment: @Constantinius I stopped with `using namespace std` and `std::endl` was to much to write. :)

Comment: @alex vasi, Joachim Pileborg: thanks, nice to know.

Comment: @constantinius: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt11ch25s02.html

Comment: There may be a slight performance difference between the two (though I wouldn't guess which is faster) but you're doing (slow) I/O already, so it hardly matters.  And `'\n'` would probably be better in a very memory-tight environment but it's unlikely you'd be using std::anything in such a case.

Comment: @Joachim: You stopped using it for the wrong reasons, but atleast you stopped using it. ;)

Comment: Your edit is misleading. `std::endl` is *documented* to flush buffered streams. "Most implementations seem to flush" is another way of saying "I 've been lucky so far" -- but to be fair, this only matters if you care about flush timings (which is very very rare IMHO).

Comment: @HotLicks: it might matter a lot, see the story I linked to in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8311177/140719).

Comment: Do most implementations flush `std::out` on newline even when it's writing to a file, or do they detect when it's a terminal and act accordingly?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Actually, `'\n'` should be the default. Unless you want to also explicitly flush the stream (and when and why would you want to do that?), there is no need to use `std::endl` at all.<sup>1</sup>
Of course, many books and tutorials use `std::endl` as the default. That is unfortunate and might lead to [serious performance bugs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=1878187#1878187).

I suppose there's little difference between using `'\n'` or using `"\n"`, but the latter is an array of (two) characters, which has to be printed character by character, for which a loop has to be set up, which is more complex than outputting a single character. Of course, when doing IO this rarely matters, but if in doubt, when you want to output one character literal, output a character literal, rather than a whole string literal.
A nice side-effect of doing so is that you communicate in your code that you *intended* to output only a single character, and not just accidentally did this.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sup><sub>Note that `std::cout` is tied to `std::cin` by default, which leads to `std::cout` being flushed before any input operation, so that any prompt will be printed before the user has to input something.</sub></sup>

Comment: `'\n'` can in certain situations really be measurably faster than `"\n"`. So it should be a habit to use that, but of course when you want it to be part of a string `"foobar\n"` is the way to go. It might also make sense to -- when your implementation provides a way -- turn of autoflush for `\n`, which will speed up certain things even more. To make things round, `std::cerr` is unbuffered and there is not really a difference then, but for `std::clog` there is of course.

Comment: OTOH, if you want to indicate progress by outputting "...", you might want to call `flush` after each `'.'`!

Comment: @curiousguy: Yeah, that's a valid example for when you really want to flush the stream. IME, those are rare, though.

Comment: There is a lot of premature micro-optimization going.g on here.

Comment: @PlasmaHH "_turn of autoflush for \n_" what do you mean?

Comment: @JohnDibling: `'\n'` vs. `"\n"` is certainly a micro-optimization, but why would it be premature? You can write both, so why not write the one that conveys your intention and _might_ be faster and will not be slower? It's the same as with `++it` vs. `it++`: It rarely matters, but when it does, it pays off to be used to writing the one which is faster where it matters.

Comment: It's premature because it has not been proved that inserting `"\n"` vs inserting `'\n'` is a bottleneck in the code.  Profile first, them optimize.

Comment: @John: equally though, `"\n"` is premature pessimization. OK, so it's *probably* some insignificant amount slower, and that's good because you want to prove that you're wise to the risk of premature optimization by deliberately writing code you think is slow. But you don't *know* that it's slower, and you have to write something, so which do you choose? Since there's no difference in comprehensibility, I think it's reasonable to write either, for pretty much any reason, including a naive guess that it's possibly some iota faster, or emits smaller code

Comment: @JohnDibling: I wasn't explaining my point as clear as I should have. We are _not_ talking about an optimization here. We are talking about picking one of two possibilities, where one is more expressive, unlikely to be slower, and likely to be faster.

Comment: @Steve:  I'm not trying to prove anything.  The point that I really had in my mind, but completely failed to convey, is that this simply isn't worth fretting over until the profiler tells you to.  You're right -- I don't really know that one is slower than the other.  Your question, "Which do you choose?" hits the nail right on the head.  That's the big question, and my default answer would be, "Do what you would normally do." (continued...)

Comment: (...continued from above) That might seem a bit open-ended -- it's certainly open to interpretation.  For my part, I always insert single chars as single chars -- so, ironically, that's what I'd do here, too.  The reason I would do this for `'\n'` is because I'd do it for `char c = 'A';` -- not because `'\n'` might be marginally faster.

Comment: @sbi:  I see.  I agree with the idea to "[pick] one of two possibilities, where one is more expressive."  However, once you added the criteria "unlikely to be slower, and likely to be faster" without having demonstrated that this is a real problem with respect to performance, that's where I diverge.

Comment: @John: I think the question is about what habits to get into, i.e. "what should I normally do -- given that the options all look about the same to me, is there any basis at all for a rule of thumb?". Naive guesses about performance are as good a tie-breaker as any IMO. As far as avoiding `std::endl` is concerned, I think that "don't tell the program to do extra work that you don't want" is a perfectly reasonable rule of thumb even in the absence of profiling. It's then a bit hair-splitty whether `"\n"` is in the same category, whether a string literal is in a sense "more" than a char literal.

Comment: @sbi:  I fall on the same side with `++it` vs `it++` as well.  There was a time, long ago, when I was naive enough to believe that `++it` "is faster" than `it++` -- so I established my norm to be to use `++it` in all cases unless I had a reason not to.  Now I know "better," and while I still use `++it` as a matter of course, it's not because of performance anymore.  Now it's simply because *that's what I always do*.

Comment: @SteveJessop:  You're right -- at the end of the day, it really doesn't matter a whole lot.  It surely doesn't matter as much as it would seem, given the energy the three of us are investing in to this conversation.  I agree completely about using a naive guess about **whatever** is as good a criteria as any when deciding what your personal coding standards are.  That's exactly what I did with `++it` vs `it++`.  Nevertheless, it's still kind of fun to talk about.

Comment: @John: agreed, I think the interest is the meta-level of how we develop our coding idioms, rather than anything to do with `'\n'` or `"\n"`. Anybody who cared about any possible performance difference between the two could have at least attempted to test it by now, but it's much more interesting to talk about programming in general!

Comment: This conversation has convinced me to alter my approach to establishing new personal coding standards.  Yesterday, naive guesses about performance would never have entered in to the equation.  Moving forward, however, I will not dismiss those naive guesses out-of-hand, and will let them be a potential variable in the consideration set.

Comment: @John: `++it` vs. `it++` doesn't matter at all in 99.99% of all cases. But since it doesn't matter, why not make a habit of using the one that's faster in those 0.01%? There's many cases where you need to pick a default: making one-arg ctors `explicit`, making functions `const`, pre- vs. post-increment, `'\n'` vs. `std::endl`,... Why not trying to _always do_ the one that has an advantage, no matter how rarely the cases are and how marginally the advantage? If you can pick either one, why not pick the one that has an advantage in 0.01%, if it has no disadvantage in the remaining 99.99%?

Comment: @sbi: In your answer far far above, you mention that "\n" is an array of two characters that must be looped over, which is of course technically correct but could be misleading to a novice.  Only the \n itself is output, the second char (a terminating \0) is not.  Of course on some platforms (DOS/Windoze) the \n itself is translated on output to two chars (\r followed by \n), but that occurs regardless of whether the caller sent a '\n' char literal or "\n" string literal.

Comment: BTW, I am *totally* with you on the "given two options of equal difficulty, you might as well pick the one more likely to result in more efficient code" thing.  It seems like some folks purposefully pick the way more likely to result in less efficient code just so they can grin deviously & pull out their self-righteous soapbox about premature optimizations whenever someone comments that there's a simple twist in coding technique that's likely to be more efficient, and once adopted and second nature, may add up to a nontrivial savings over the course of a large project.

Comment: @phonetagger: Even an array with only one element is an array, and its processing needs the initialization of a loop variable, the loading of branching code into the pipeline, and whatnot.

Comment: @sbi:  Good grief.  I understand that.  My point was that your answer seems to suggest that though there's little difference between using '\n' or "\n", the latter is "an array of (two) characters, which has to be printed character by character...".  My point was simply that no more actual characters are output on the stream by using "\n", either way, the same number of characters are placed on the stream itself.  Regardless, the stream output overhead dwarfs the char array looping overhead by several orders of magnitude.  But regardless of that, I was still agreeing with you in principle.

Comment: @phonetagger +1 for your second last comment. This whole discussion was obviuously in need for such an agressively sarcastic comment. You don't need a profiler to check simple and valid reasonings about efficiency. We indeed shouldn't expect an actual performance improvement from such a minor change, but neither should we give ourselves dumber than we really are.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I have seen cases where inserting a `NOP` statement made code faster — something that certainly goes against all "simple and valid reasoning". I agree with the rest of what you said — which shouldn't be surprising, because, basically, it agrees with what I had said... `:)`

Answer (score 17):

There are no the best. You use what you need :

- '\n' - to end the line
- "some string\n" - the end the line after some string
- `std::endl` - to end the line and flush the stream

Comment: What is the simplest explanation of ***"flushing the stream"***? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Milan Imagine water flowing down a pipe. Flushing the stream pushes the water though and waits for it all to get through the pipe before sending more water in. Except that, the water cant move through until the recipient wants it, so you have to wait for the recipient to suck the water out of your pipe so you can flush more water down. This is why is rarely a good idea to flush your pipes with endl, so `'\n'` should be used.

Answer (score 15):

They do different things. `"\n"` Outputs a newline (in the appropriate platform-specific representation, so it generates a `"\r\n"` on Windows), but `std::endl` does the same **and flushes the stream**. Usually, you don't need to flush the stream immediately and it'll just cost you performance, so for the most part there's no reason to use `std::endl`.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: I worded my answer poorly, which may have lead people to believe that I thought "\n" actually printed a null character. This is of course wrong :)

Edit 2: Having looked at a C++ reference, `char`s are passed by reference anyway, so there's no difference there. The only difference is that the cstring will have to be searched for a delimiting character. *The below isn't correct due to this fact.*

`'\n'` would be ever so slightly more efficient than `"\n"`, because the latter also contains a null character on the end, which means you're sending a `char*` to `operator<<()` (usually 4 bytes on a 32-bit system) as opposed to a single byte for a `char`.

In practice, this is borderline irrelevant. Personally, I follow the convention that Vladimir outlined.*

Comment: because it's wrong? Why would `\n` generate a null character?

Comment: Because it's a cstring. A single `char` ('\n') will take up 1 byte, whereas cstrings are implicitly appended with a null character, hence "\n" is actually "\n\0". It's a trivial issue nonetheless. For example, `sizeof("\n");` returns 2 on my machine.

Comment: So? If I write `std::cout << "hello " << "world", then what will actually be printed will have a null character in the middle of it? I think not. :) The string "\n" is null-terminated, sure, but when that string is writtten to a stream, the null byte is not written. Anything else would be crazy and lead to null bytes scattered all over your strings. The null byte is not part of the string, it is used to delimit it.

Comment: "_you're sending two bytes into the stream instead of one_" you might want to clarify this: some people might understand, literally, that { NEWLINE NUL } is output instead of just NEWLINE.

Comment: I agree with that, of course the null isn't printed to the stream. My point is that the null still has to be created in memory, which implies that there is going to be an extremely minimal performance degradation. I just realised that I wrote my answer in an ambiguous manner. I believe that the entire cstring is passed into `operator<<()`, which will only print the '\n'.

Comment: Again, no. The string `"\n"` (with the terminating null) has static storage duration, it doesn't ened to be constructed at runtime at all.

Comment: Good point. I'll admit defeat at that. My theory is moot regardless, since it was based on the passing of data by value, when it's not for obvious reasons (cstrings can't be passed by value... what was I thinking?). I originally thought you were denying that "\n" was 2 bytes wide, which was why I contested your downvote :)

Comment: @jalf But still there is a cost for iterating over an array of chars until the `'\0'` is found.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yeah, but in the case of "\n" vs '\n' that cost would be very minimal.

Comment: @ChrisParton Of course we're all speaking about minimality here, but your answer wasn't completely wrong and there is indeed a performance difference between `'\n'` and `"\n"`.

Comment: True about `'\n'` vs `"\n"`. I was thinking of `"\n"` compared to `std::endl`.

Comment: It's been an interesting discussion at any rate. The main issue with my answer was that it was poorly worded. I thought about the cost of seeking the null character, but @jalf trumped my main argument with the static storage remark. Rookie mistake on my part haha.

Comment: "you're sending a char* to operator<<() (usually 4 bytes on a 32-bit system) as opposed to a single byte for a char." This still isn't quite right, since a 32 bit calling convention is, I think, unlikely to pass a `char` argument in less than 4 bytes of register or stack. It's just that 3 of them will be either zeroed by the caller, sign-extended by the caller, or ignored by the callee. As you say, borderline irrelevant :-)

Comment: Yeah, that is wrong. I edited my post, made it italic and wrote "This is wrong," but I think @ChristianRau was editing the post at nearly the same time and it overwrote my changes. Ay any rate, the `char` is passed by reference, so my point is irrelevant haha. I'll re-edit the post. Edit: My bad, the text saying that it was wrong is still there, just not the italics.

Comment: @Chris Sorry for the edit, but I thought the italics were a typo, since they used the `*` from `char*` and this ended up as a simple `char` which was just wrong.

Answer (score 4):

- `std::cout << variable << std::endl;`

  `std::endl` output a newline, but it also flushes the output stream. In other words, same effect as

  ```
  std::cout << variable << '\n'; // output newline
  std::cout.flush();      // then flush
  ```
- `std::cout << variable << '\n';`

  `'\n'` output a newline for a `char,` hence `ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, char c);` will be used.
- `std::cout << variable << "\n";`

  `"\n"` is a `const char[2]`, so `ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);` will be used. We can imagine, this function will contain a loop, we might argue is overkill to just print out a newline.

Answer (score 3):

`std::endl` flushes the stream. When this something you want to happen -- e.g. because you expect your output to be made visible to the user in a timely fashion -- you should use `std::endl` instead of writing `'\n'` to the stream (whether as an isolated character or part of a string).

Sometimes, you can get away without explicitly flushing the stream yourself; e.g. in a linux environment, if `cout` is synchronized with `STDOUT` (this is the default) and is writing to a terminal, then by default, the stream will be *line buffered* and will automatically flush every time you write a new line.

However, it is risky to rely on this behavior. e.g. in the same linux environment, if you decide to run your program with `stdout` being redirected to a file or piped to another process, then by default, the stream will be *block buffered* instead.

Similarly, if you later decide to turn off synchronization with stdio (e.g. for efficiency), then implementations will tend to use `iostream`'s buffering mechanisms, which doesn't have a line buffering mode.

I have seen much wasted productivity due to this mistake; if output should be visible when it is written, then you should either use `std::endl` explicitly (or use `std::flush` or `std::ostream::flush`, but I usually find `std::endl` more convenient), or do something else that ensures flushing happens often enough, such as configuring `stdout` to be line buffered (assuming that's adequate).