# C++ chaining of the operator << for std::cout like usage

Tags: c++, operators, chaining

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::endl is of unknown type when overloading operator<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134388/stdendl-is-of-unknown-type-when-overloading-operator)
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

I'm currently programming a logger class, but the `operator<<` method causes a compiler error. Here's a minimized version of the class, in file "logger.h":

```
#include <iostream>
class Logger {
public:
    Logger() : m_file(std::cout) {}

    template <typename T>
    Logger &operator<<(const T &a) {
        m_file<<a;
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    std::ostream& m_file;
};
```

It is included in my main.cpp and works perfecly when I output a string literal:

```
log << "hi";
```

However, the following won't compile.

```
#include "logger.h"
int main() {
    Logger log;

    log << std::endl;
}
```

The g++ compiler reports:

> src/main.cpp:5: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'log << std::endl'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is not about the chain of `<<` , a single `log << endl` would also cause the problem. It is because `std::endl` is a template function:

```
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
```

One of the overload of `operator<<` in `basic_ostream` is:

```
template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
class basic_ostream : virtual public basic_ios<charT,traits> {
public:
    basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(
    basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&));
//...
};
```

So the template parameters can be deduced when `std::cout<<std::endl` is used. However, when the left side is the `class Logger`, the compile cannot deduce the template parameters of `endl`. Explicitly give the template parameters can let program compile and work:

```
#include <iostream>
class Logger
{
public:
    std::ostream &m_file;
    Logger(std::ostream &o = std::cout):m_file(o){};

    template <typename T>
    Logger &operator<<(const T &a) {
        m_file<<a;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Logger log;
    log<<std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >;
    log<<"hi"<<" stackoverflow"<<std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >;
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can add a new overload of `operator<<` in `class Logger` to let compiler deduce the template parameters of `std::endl`:

```
#include <iostream>
class Logger
{
public:
    std::ostream &m_file;
    Logger(std::ostream &o = std::cout):m_file(o){};

    template <typename T>
    Logger &operator<<(const T &a) {
        m_file<<a;
        return *this;
    }

    Logger &operator<<(std::ostream& (*pf) (std::ostream&)){
        m_file<<pf;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Logger log;
    log<<std::endl;
    log<<"hi"<<" stackoverflow"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, if you don't need the output to be flushed immediately, you can use '\n' instead of `endl`.

Comment: "Also, you can use '\n' instead of `endl`." Not if the OP wants to make sure the output buffers are flushed, as I [recently learned](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8311058/440558).

Comment: Right, I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `std::endl` which is a function. Refer to:

[std::endl is of unknown type when overloading operator<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134388/stdendl-is-of-unknown-type-when-overloading-operator)

Comment: I think Eric wanted to say that `std::endl` is a function.

Comment: I guess you mean "`std::endl` is a function template"?

Comment: @Mike, well, `std::endl` is not a template itself. It takes and returns a templated class, yes, but it's only a member function. Its declaration looks like `template<class charT, class traits> basic_ostream<charT, traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os);`.

Comment: @jalf, just correct the wording, I mean "std::endl" ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: That looks a lot like a function template to me. And it's not a member of anything.

Comment: Ah right, makes more sense then. :)