# C++ strange behavior of a for cycle initialization

Tags: c++

I noticed a strange behavior of a for cycle...

**Case 1:**

Let us have an internal initialization of i variable

```
for ( int i=10; i <=10; i++)
{
    std::cout << i;
}
return 0;
```

Output:

```
10
```

**Case 2:**

Now we initialize i outside the cycle

```
int i = 10;

for ( ; i <=10; i++)
{
    std::cout << i;
}
return 0;
```

Output:

```
Nothing will be print
```

**Case 3:**

Initialization any variable not related to i:

```
int i = 10;

for ( int k = 0 ; i <=10; i++)
{
    std::cout << i;
}
return 0;
```

Output:

```
10
```

**Question**

How can depend a result of a cycle condition on the place where we initialize variable i?

**Updated results**

I traced a code using degugger and VS 2010 really jumps over a cycle in case 2. 
However g++ works well.
Maybe a bug in compiler?

**Fianal results**
After reboot it works correcly. Something between heaven and earth. 
Sorry for the useless question....

Comment: Both 2 and 3 should print 10.

Comment: Second one should print `10`. Are you sure you didn't overlook something?

Comment: Please review the output of your case 2: http://ideone.com/alc3j

Comment: You're doing something else not shown in the code snippets here.

Comment: I think you did not run your compiler properly or you did not show us the full source, see [this program](http://ideone.com/kcIqA), it seems to be your 'case 2' but it prints `10`.

Comment: VS 2010 has a mature compiler, it should print `10`. Perhaps you should follow Andreas' advice and flush the output.

Comment: @iccthedral And indeed it does. Just tested in VC++2010 ("only" Express version though) and it works just fine. With or without newlines or manual flushes.

Comment: @justik Can you post a complete program (including main) that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Try again with flushing.

Comment: @ Andreas Brinck: This is a complete program, such a simple construction :-)

Comment: Would you just c/p it, as it is, so we could get this done. This doesn't make any sense if the outputs are consistent. 
Then again, I've seen trolls wandering near `c++` woods.

Comment: It does print 10 in MSVC 2010.

Comment: @justik I want the complete code that can be pasted into a single translation unit and compiled into an executable which reproduces this problem, the above doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If case 2 doesn't print `10` you have a bug in your compiler or the output isn't being flushed. Add a `<< "\n"` to the output as well.

Comment: Actually, just adding `'\n'` doesn't flush the output, as I discovered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8311058/440558). However, the program terminating should _definitely_ flush the output.

Comment: But If it flushes when `i` is initilized at loop and it doesn't flush when i is initilized before loop is also a bug in compiler. But I don't think VS will do that.

Comment: @ Andreas it looks like a VS 2010 compiler bug, g++ works well

Comment: I would be very surprised if this was a VS 2010 compiler bug, it's not like you're at the frontier of C++ features :)

Comment: @justik VS2010 works as expected on my windows 7 x64 machine.

Answer (score 0):

The second one prints `10` too. If it doesn't there is a bug in your compiler or you are using a wrong compiler.

I've run the same code in [`http://ideone.com/UB0V0`](http://ideone.com/UB0V0). you can have a see it it. it prints `10`