# Expecting a primary-expression before " / " when one is not necessary

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, expression

I have done a simple program testing pointers, references, and recursion.

Here is the code to overlook (the problem is complained to come from PassAddresses' function):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
long RecRecur(short &caps);
void PassAddresses(short &address, short &address2, const char *nosey);
int main(int args, char **LOC)
{
short test = 15;
const char rosey = 0;
short myLick = 500;
short PersonalWhim = 250;
const char *LOG = &rosey;
RecRecur(test);
PassAddresses(myLick, PersonalWhim, LOG);
}
void PassAddresses(short &address, short &address2, const char *nosey)
{
address = address + address;
address2 += address;
for(short i = 100; i < 1000; i++)
{
for(short c = 50; c != 120; c++)
{
cout << "These are just for-loop tests...." << /n;
}
}
cout << address << /n << address2 << /n << nosey << /n << &rosey;
}
long RecRecur(short &caps)
{
caps--;
if(caps > 0x7CDE)
{
RecRecur();
}
else return;
}
```

Basically the compiler is complaining that a "primary-expression" is expected before the "/" character, and I am clueless on what the issue could be. The expressions/operators on the "address" value are perfectly interchangeable.

Comment: What's the `/n` in that line supposed to mean?

Comment: A newline, what else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311058/n-or-n-or-stdendl-to-stdcout

Comment: The issue thrown is not towards the "/n", but before it.

Comment: A newline character is spelled `'\n'`, as you can also see in the question you've linked to. Please make sure you got basic syntax issues like this right before being conscending.

Comment: Right, the compiler has no idea what you're trying to divide by n.

Comment: I changed it to that in my IDE, compiled, and get the following error: control reaches end of non-void function. Check my updated code above now, fixed.

Comment: Please don't make changes to the original code based on answers.  That will invalidate them.

Comment: where is your return value in your `int main()`?

Comment: @UnholySheep: There is none, but I assume the `else return` is for another function.  It's hard to tell with the lack of indentation.

Comment: @Jamal: after counting the brackets, I find that the `else return`is for his `RecRecur()` function, but that cannot be correct? If it does actually work then it is still very bad style. But his second issue was probably caused by the lack of return in the `main()`

Comment: @UnholySheep: Yep, not right.  `RecRecur()` returns a `long`; it's not `void`.  The explicit return in `main()` is not really needed in C++, but it doesn't hurt to have it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**1. The escape character is '\', not '/'.**

> > cout << address << /n << address2 << /n << nosey << /n << &rosey;

change above line with

```
cout << address << "\n" << address2 << "\n" << nosey << "\n" << &nosey;
```

or

```
cout << address << endl << address2 << endl << nosey << endl << &nosey;
```

**2. Notice that you have a type in the same line. You may want to write `nosey` not `rosey` :)**

**3. RecRecur(); takes an argument please give one.**

**4. RecRecur() has to return a `long`**

Comment: also fix mentioned typo :)

Comment: @user2948710: Who is rosey by the way ;)

Answer (score 2):

The escape character '\', not '/'.  It also needs to be inside quotes:

```
cout << "hello world" << '\n';
```

Comment: Well then why not tell us what those errors are so we can help you with them?

Comment: I updated my code and fixed everything, so now you can see it above.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple syntax error - a newline is `endl`, not `\n`.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311058/n-or-n-or-stdendl-to-stdcout

Comment: I don't think suggesting that someone who can't debug an obvious syntax error needs to make decisions about when to flush standard output and when not to is a good idea. Keep it simple. When you understand the basics, then worry about details.

Comment: Yes, but it forces you to decide when to flush and when not to. There's no reason to make things more complicated.

Comment: @user2948710 Yeah, `"/n"` works. It's the string containing a slash character and the lower case letter n. I doubt that's what you wanted. `/n` without quotes, however, is simply a syntax error. Feel free to get a copy of the standard and check the grammar.

Comment: I understand that, but I fixed it and there's still issues. Look above, I updated everything.