# Benchmarking linefeed characters vs std::endl

Tags: c++

I'm reading [`“\n” or '\n' or std::endl to std::cout?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311058/n-or-n-or-stdendl-to-stdcout). Despite the consensus that it really doesn't matter what you choose, I decided to construct a contrived test that would measure the program execution speed of each. Here is my simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
    {
    #ifdef VER1
        std::cout << "\n";
    #endif
    #ifdef VER2
        std::cout << '\n';
    #endif
    #ifdef VER3
        std::cout << std::endl;
    #endif
    }
}
```

Using one billion iterations and `-O3` and redirecting output to `/dev/null/`, these are my results:

```
"\n"
0:30.96

'\n'
0:31.66
```

With `-O2`:

```
"\n"
0:32.96

'\n'
0:31.54
```

Why does a higher optimization level make `'\n'` **slower**?

Comment: It depends on your compiler. Look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: Are those seconds? Did you repeat the results a few times? It could just be noise.

Answer (score 0):

With this setup, you're most likely measuring which test run happened to get interrupted the longest by the thread scheduler. Also, I imagine you might get very different times from writing to a real file instead of /dev/null.