# Why is endl slower than \n (newline)?

Tags: c++, string, performance

Many people say that in C++ `endl` is much slower than `\n` when printing a string. They explain that `endl` flushes the buffer and `\n` doesn't. In the book C Primer Plus it's said that

> "Sending the output from the buffer to the screen or file is called
>   flushing the buffer."

and that

> "The standard C rules for when output is sent from the buffer to the
>   screen are clear: It is sent when the buffer gets full, when a newline
>   character is encountered, or when there is impending input."

So isn't technically printing an newline character flushing the buffer and still why is `endl` slower ?

Comment: To my knowledge, `endl` is a C++ only construct - so the C Primer Plus might not be the best place to check for its behavior.

Comment: Your quote about "the standard C rules for when output is sent from the buffer" are wrong. And the standard C rules only matter when iostreams are synchronized with stdio (which basically requires that iostream foregos its buffering mechanism and immediately forwards everything along to stdio calls).

Comment: Also see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8311177/440558