# how to print my name in next line in C++

Tags: c++

I want to print my name ten times in new lines. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>


using namespace std;
void main()
{



    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
        cout <<   "krishna "  ;
    getchar();

}
```

I need a break or "\n" after the first row of printing. How to get that ?

Comment: If you know you need a `\n` why did you not try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT use std::endl;

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    cout <<   "krishna "  << endl;
```

Its indeed (after getting an comment) better to use '\n' (Windows only)

Look at this FAQ -> https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#endl-vs-slash-n

Comment: Most of the time you actually do not want to use `std::endl`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311058/n-or-n-or-stdendl-to-stdcout

Answer (score 0):

You can use Both endl or '\n'.your code will look like this-

```
for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
cout<<"Krishna\n";
```