# changing printf to cout

Tags: c++, printing, cout

I am still a bit unfamiliar with C++ and need some help with using `cout`.

```
int main()
{
    char letterGrades[25] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', };

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d] --> %c", i, letterGrades[i]);

        if (i == 3)      // how can I print \n when i == 7 , 11 , 15 , 19....
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I am trying to do, and it works perfectly fine. However, I don't know how to write this code using cout.

Also, I would print the result in a 4 in a row tabulate format.
so result can look something like this

```
[0] --> A [1] --> A [2] --> A [3] --> A
[4] --> A [5] --> A [6] --> A [7] --> A
[8] --> A [9] --> A [10] --> A [11] --> A
```

Comment: `cout << i << " --> " << letterGrades[i];`

Comment: And for newline you do: `cout << endl;`, all assuming that you are `using namespace std`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class of which `cout` is an instance has clever overloads to `<<` for many types, including `char`, `int`, and `const char[]` (for string literals):

So you can write

```
std::cout << "[" << i << "] --> " << letterGrades[i];
```

in place of your first `printf` and

```
std::cout << "\n";
```

for the second one. You can use `"\t"` to inject a tabulation character into the stream.

All this comes at a slight performance hit, which ought to be negligible cf. the I/O on your platform.

Also, consider reading [C++: "std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n) for further study.

Finally, use

```
if (i % 4 == 3){
    // i is 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, etc
}
```

for your conditional check for the periodic newlines. `%` is the *remainder* operator.

Comment: I think `std::cout << '\n';` is even better than `std::cout << "\n";` http://stackoverflow.com/a/8311177/3313064

Answer (score 0):

Inside for loop something like this:

```
std::cout << "[" << i << "]" << "-->" << letterGrades[i]; 
if (i == 3){ 
     std::cout << "\n"; 
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't leave a line break after every 3rd column

Answer (score 0):

its pretty easy actually

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
 cout << "[" << i << "] --> " << letterGrades[i] << (i%3==0)?endl:""; 
}
```

Let me explain the code

1. cout takes bitwise operations to pass in a stream. What that basically means is
   that you need to use "<<" operator to tell it what to print.
2. The last bit `(i%3==0)?endl:""`. If you're not familiar with the `?` operator, what that does is if the condition that appears within `()` is true, it'll evaluate the part before `:`, if not then it'll evaluate the later

e.g.:-

```
print((1>0)?"Hello":"World") \\ Output: Hello
print((false)?"Hello":"World") \\ Output: World
```

3. `%` is also a neat operator we can use. It divides a number and returns the remainder.

e.g.:-

```
print(10%5) \\ Output: 0
print(5%2) \\ Output: 1
```

So I used that to see if there should be a line terminator `endl` ("\n") after the third column,

Hope this helps

Comment: Drop the first sentence and I'll upvote. By the release of the film "Interstellar", where the GCI guys used General Relativity equations to model the wormhole graphics, they found that easy.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to insert a newline (or std::endl) after each 3rd, 7th, 11th, etc, line is probably to have an int to count each step

```
int endl_count = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
  {
    std::cout << '[' << i << ']' << " --> " << letterGrades[i];
    if (endl_count == 3) {
      endl_count = 0;
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    endl_count++;
  }
```

Also: to get the size of an array you can do

```
(sizeof(array) / sizeof(datatype))
```

So in your case you can do

```
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(letterGrades) / sizeof(char)); i++)
```

instead of hardcoding the `25`