# C++ how to allow user to choose choice

Tags: c++

Hi i dont know how to allow the user to choose one of the choices i provided in my code and if they picked a choice that was not given then i want the program to return to the last point.

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

//Welcoming message with date//
cout << "Welcome to FILM Screen Cinema" << endl;


cout << endl;
cout << "ENTER STAFF/OPERATOR'S NAME: ";
string name;
cin >> name;

cout << endl;
cout << "ENTER DATE:";
string date;
cin >> date;

cout << endl;
cout << "CHOOSE A MOVIE THAT IS SCREENING TODAY:" << endl;
cout << "[1] Deadpool" << endl << "[2] Goosebumps" <<endl;
string input;
cin >> input;


}
```

Where it says choose a movie, i want the user to type either 1 or 2 for the choices but if they type any other number then it should say invalid and allow them to type 1 or 2 again. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Someone help please?

Comment: How ironclad do you want this? How should it handle "booger booger booger 1 booger"?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want each of the `std::cin >> XXX` calls to actually query the user for input. That is currently not the case, for example when the user types "John Smith" as the name of the operator, `name` will be set to "John", and the following `std::cin >> date` reuses the remaining part "Smith" instead of asking for input again.

To fix this, you can use `std::getline`.

The first part of your code should thus be replaced by

```
std::cout << '\n';
std::cout << "ENTER STAFF/OPERATOR'S NAME: ";
std::string name;
std::getline(std::cin, name);

std::cout << '\n';
std::cout << "ENTER DATE:";
std::string date;
std::getline(std::cin, date);

std::cout << '\n';
```

The same is true for the part where you validate the input. Now you only need to add a `while`-loop to keep asking the user for new input if the previous one was invalid.

```
std::cout << "CHOOSE A MOVIE THAT IS SCREENING TODAY:\n";
std::cout << "[1] Deadpool\n"
          << "[2] Goosebumps\n";

std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);

while(input != "1" && input != "2") {
    std::cout << "Invalid!\n\n";

    std::cout << "CHOOSE A MOVIE THAT IS SCREENING TODAY:\n";
    std::cout << "[1] Deadpool\n"
              << "[2] Goosebumps\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
}

if (input == "1") {
    // do something
} else if (input == "2") {
    // do something else
}
```

Btw, please consider reading [“\n” or '\n' or `std::endl` to `std::cout`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311177/3601321) and [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3601321)

Comment: @user4581301 You're right. I replaced it with `std::getline(std::cin, input)`.