# Triangle Loop Last Row

Tags: c++

I  want to make a triangle with this pattern:

```
1
11
111
```

then repeat the last row as much as how many rows in it:

```
1
11
111
111
111
111
```

I already made code for the triangle pattern, but I'm stuck on looping the last row. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int rows;
    cin>>rows;

    for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout<<"1";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Obligatory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311058/n-or-n-or-stdendl-to-stdcout?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The part you want to add is just like the triangle, but every row is the same length.  The code should reflect this.

Comment: Hint: One way to do it is to make a *new* `for` loop inside your main function, after the end of your first `for` loop.

Comment: Instead of making another loop you could just use `std::min()` in a strategic place.

Answer (score 1):

I already found a way to do it,
I add a new for loop after my first loop and it works :D

here's the code

```
    for(int l=1;l<=rows;l++){
    for(int k=1;k<=rows;k++){
        cout<<"1";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you so much!